# Ajax does not return php echo

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I tried to check onblur if the entry number is already available in the database. When exsist i want show table. Everything works fine on localhost xampp but when i tried do this on wordpress page ajax return nothing.When i wrote text above `<?php` , ajax return this but echo from php no. Where is difference? Is something what I must add to this code when i use it on wordpress page ?

```
    <script>
    function checkAvailability() {

      //alert(document.getElementById("f_numer").value);
        jQuery.ajax({
        url: "check_availability.php",
        data:'f_numer='+document.getElementById("f_numer").value,
        type: "POST",
        success:function(data){
        console.log(data);
            $("#tab").html(data);
        if(data != 0)
        {
          var element = document.getElementById("tablica");
          element.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth", block: "start", inline: "nearest"});

        }


        },
        error:function (){
      }
        });
    }
    </script>
```

```
 <?php

require("/wp-content/zwroty_edycja/dbcontroller.php");
$db_handle = new DBController();

if(!empty($_POST["f_numer"])) {

$query = "SELECT * FROM bledy WHERE `Nr_zamówienia`='" . $_POST["f_numer"] . "'";

$numer_count = $db_handle->numRows($query);
if($numer_count>0) {
 $conn = $db_handle->connectDB();

      $result = $conn->query($query);
      //echo ('<p id="tekst">'.$sql.'</br>Liczba pozycji: '.$result->num_rows."</p>");
      echo ('<p id="tekst">Liczba pozycji: '.$result->num_rows."</p>");
      if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

          while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $kolumny[] = $row;
          }

          $kolumny = array_reverse($kolumny,true);

          foreach($kolumny as $row)
          {
              echo "
              <tr><td>{$row["Id"]}</td>
              <td>{$row["Data"]}</td>
              <td>{$row["Firma"]}</td>
              <td>{$row["Nr_zamówienia"]}</td>
              <td>{$row["Imię_nazwisko"]}</td>
              <td>{$row["Zwrot_wymiana"]}</td>
              <td>{$row["Model_auta"]}</td>
              <td>{$row["Rodzaj_produktu"]}</td>
              <td>{$row["Przyczyna_zwrotu"]}</td>
              <td>{$row["Sposób_rozwiązania"]}</td>
              <td>{$row["Koszty_łączne"]}</td>
              <td>{$row["Przyjmująca_zamówienie"]}</td>
              <td>{$row["Osoba_odpowiedzialna_nr_1"]}</td>
              <td>{$row["Osoba_odpowiedzialna_nr_2"]}</td>
              <td>{$row["Osoba_odpowiedzialna_nr_3"]}</td>
              <td>{$row["Osoba_przyjmująca"]}
              </td></tr>";
          }


      }

    $conn->close();


}else{

}
}
?>
```

[image]

Comment: check you for loop and while loop is working?? check both

Comment: Can you see what's been sent in the Network tab? Show us a screenshot of POST Request Parameters in the Network tab after the AJAX call is made. A sample one is: https://i.imgur.com/R3DhTqI.png

Comment: You can clearly see the request is a 500, what is the actual error message in your PHP logs?

Comment: The path in your `require` statement is most certainly wrong. (A leading slash refers to the root directory of the server file system, and that is very likely _not_ the place where your `wp-content` folder resides.)

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman https://i.imgur.com/R3DhTqI.png

Comment: @Ł.Strzelczyk That's my image! LoL.

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman sry here you are: https://ibb.co/SRXVLXD

Comment: @Ł.Strzelczyk It's not accessible. Can you use imgur.com?

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman It`s return "f_numer : 123354567" and it`s correct like on you pic (i have a little problem with imgur)

Comment: Okay, then it's weird.

Answer (score 0):

You must use ajax properly

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#example').DataTable({
                'processing': true,
                'serverSide': true,
                'serverMethod': 'post',
                'ajax': {
                    'url':'force_ajaxfile.php',
                    data: {
                            source1:  "<?php echo $ser_off; ?>"
                        },
                },  'columns': [
                    { data: 'full_name' },
                    { data: 'service_email' },
                    { data: 'service_mobile' },
                    { data: 'service_name_record_office_address' },
                    { data: 'elector_type' },

                ]
            });
```

Force-ajaxfiles.php

```
    $serv_id = $_POST['source1'];



$draw = $_POST['draw'];
$row = $_POST['start'];
$rowperpage = $_POST['length']; // Rows display per page
$columnIndex = $_POST['order'][0]['column']; // Column index
$columnName = $_POST['columns'][$columnIndex]['data']; // Column name
$columnSortOrder = $_POST['order'][0]['dir']; // asc or desc
$searchValue = $_POST['search']['value']; // Search value
## Search 
$searchQuery = " ";
if($searchValue != ''){
    $searchQuery = " and (full_name like '%".$searchValue."%' or 
        service_email like '%".$searchValue."%' or 
        service_mobile like'%".$searchValue."%' ) ";
}
## Total number of records without filtering
    $sql = "select count(*) as allcount from `personal-records`
        where `service_service_regment_id` = '$serv_id'";
    $sel = mysqli_query($connect,$sql);
    $records = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sel);
    $totalRecords = $records['allcount'];

    ## Total number of records with filtering
    $sel = mysqli_query($connect,"select count(*) as allcount from `personal-records`
                            WHERE 1 ".$searchQuery."
                            and `service_service_regment_id` = '$serv_id'");
    $records = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sel);
    $totalRecordwithFilter = $records['allcount'];

    ## Fetch records
    $empQuery = "select * from `personal-records`
                WHERE 1 ".$searchQuery."
                and  `service_service_regment_id` = '$serv_id'
                order by ".$columnName." ".$columnSortOrder."
                limit ".$row.",".$rowperpage;
    $empRecords = mysqli_query($connect, $empQuery);
    $data = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($empRecords)) {


    $data[] = array(
            "full_name"=>$row['full_name'],
            "service_email"=> $row['service_email'],
            "service_mobile"=> $row['service_mobile'],
            "service_name_record_office_address"=> $row['id'],
            "elector_type"=>$row['addres']
        );
}
## Response
$response = array(
    "draw" => intval($draw),
    "iTotalRecords" => $totalRecords,
    "iTotalDisplayRecords" => $totalRecordwithFilter,
    "aaData" => $data
);

echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: I'm a little confused by this answer. First thing is that the OP appears to be using wordpress which you completely ignore in your php answer. Second is that he apparently (judging by the javascript code) already has a table and only puts the focus on that on success. So I don't get why you just use Datatables instead of improving OP's code. But I have to admin that the second point is debatable since I'm not a javascript expert.

Comment: @LLJ97 You're right. Subop has pasted a code that applies entirely to something else. As I wrote above, the code works on xamp, I wonder what is the difference in wordpress.

Comment: Third thing I just noticed is that this php code is wide open to sql injection.